# copy information to an external workbook

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am writing a macro where I take data from a CSV and copy it to another Excel file (not the current or active file).

What is the code to take the copied data and send it to another file in the same directory.

This is my code, I have commented out the lines that cause the macro not to work. I want to set the variable `wshT` to Sheet1 of the WTF.xlsx file, which is in the same directory but not the active workbook. I have not opened that one. So the goal is to use this macro to copy extra data from the CSV and send it to the WTF.xlsx file and save it as something new, in this case "BBB". Any help is much appreciated. When I uncomment those lines, errors pop up.

```
Sub Import()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    'Dim strFileName1 As String
    MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    strFileName = MyPath & "\borgwich_die_BM1940_profile.csv"
    'strFileName1 = Workbooks("WTF.xlsx").Activate
    'strFileName1 = Workbooks("WTF.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Dim wbkS As Workbook
    Dim wshS As Worksheet
    Dim wshT As Worksheet
    'Set wshT = strFileName1
    Set wbkS = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFileName)
    Set wshS = wbkS.Worksheets(1)
    wshS.Range("A1:A3").EntireRow.Delete
    'wshS.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wshT.Range("A1")
    wbkS.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & "\BBB", FileFormat _
    :=51, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: If WTF.xlsx open at this point? Is there ever a case when it would be closed and you need to open it?

Answer (score 1):

Your use of value assignment to *strFileName1* through the use of `.Activate` and/or `.Select` was bad methodology. If WTF.xlsx is open, you can directly reference its *Sheet1* and `Set` a worksheet object reference to a variable.

```
Sub Import()
    Dim MyPath As String, strFileName As String
    Dim wbkS As Workbook, wshS As Worksheet, wshT As Worksheet

    MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    strFileName = MyPath & "\borgwich_die_BM1940_profile.csv"

    Set wbkS = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFileName)
    Set wshS = wbkS.Worksheets(1)
    Set wshT = Workbooks("WTF.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

    wshS.Range("A1:A3").EntireRow.Delete
    With wshS.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .Copy Destination:=wshT.Range("A1")
    End With

    wbkS.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wshT.Parent.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & "\BBB", FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
    wshT.Parent.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Another alternative would be to use the VBA equivalent of Data ► Get External Data ► From Text but you should probably know the number and type of fields being brought in with the CSV beforehand. This is certainly the preferred method if the CSV data is being incorrectly interpreted by the temp worksheet you are creating by opening the CSV as a workbook.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped for the tip. But the problem is I get an erorr: Subscript is out of Range.

Comment: Jeeped, the error appears to be with this line: Set wshT = Workbooks("WTF.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")

Comment: I asked whether WTF.xlsx was open in a comment to your original question but that was ignored. In this reply I qualified my actions with *' If WTF.xlsx is open, you can ...'* but that seems to have been ignored as well. If it is not open, you have to open it. If you don't know if it is open, then test for it (e.g. throw an error, catch the error, and open it).